# Hamburger menu items not showing up with data-toggle in Angular

Tags: jquery, html, angular

I am learning both Angular and bootstrap. To combine those, I tried to copy some working html content to an Angular component. However, some functionality doesn't work yet. When I click at the hamburger menu icon, nothing is toggled and the nav bar items are not being displayed. This 'data-toggle' functionality seems to work with jquery and so I also tried to import scripts for this.

Here the code with the 'data-toggler':

```
<button class="navbar-toggler hidden-sm-up" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navigation"> &#9776; </button>

<div class="collapse navbar-toggleable-xs" id="navigation"> ... </div>
```

Underneath I tried to import JQuery scripts;

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha384-THPy051/pYDQGanwU6poAc/hOdQxjnOEXzbT+OuUAFqNqFjL+4IGLBgCJC3ZOShY" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.2.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-Plbmg8JY28KFelvJVai01l8WyZzrYWG825m+cZ0eDDS1f7d/js6ikvy1+X+guPIB" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ux8v3A6CPtOTqOzMKiuo3d/DomGaaClxFYdCu2HPMBEkf6x2xiDyJ7gkXU0MWwaD" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

This is the whole component:

> app.component.html

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-AysaV+vQoT3kOAXZkl02PThvDr8HYKPZhNT5h/CXfBThSRXQ6jW5DO2ekP5ViFdi" crossorigin="anonymous">
   <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alegreya+Sans:400,500,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  </head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">

  <button class="navbar-toggler hidden-sm-up" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navigation">
    &#9776;
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-toggleable-xs" id="navigation">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav float-sm-right">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#social">CONNECT</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#who">WHO</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#work">WORK</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#why">WHY</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#customers">CUSTOMERS</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#pricing">PRICING</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">CONTACT</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</nav>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha384-THPy051/pYDQGanwU6poAc/hOdQxjnOEXzbT+OuUAFqNqFjL+4IGLBgCJC3ZOShY" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.2.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-Plbmg8JY28KFelvJVai01l8WyZzrYWG825m+cZ0eDDS1f7d/js6ikvy1+X+guPIB" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ux8v3A6CPtOTqOzMKiuo3d/DomGaaClxFYdCu2HPMBEkf6x2xiDyJ7gkXU0MWwaD" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Does anyone know why the list items are not being displayed when the button has been pressed?

Answer (score 1):

Without looking into too much detail, I'll highly recommend you to not mix Angular with jQuery. This is, were all the `messing things up` starts..

[You can either use material](https://material.angularjs.org/) to build this kind of navigation or use the [Bootstrap components written in pure AngularJS by the AngularUI Team](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/). There's also a [Semantic UI Angular Integrations
Repository](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-Angular) if you aren't happy with the other two.